# Spring: annotation equivalent to BeanNameAware?

Tags: spring

Is there an annotation I can use instead of implementing BeanNameAware?

Comment: Very unlikely that a Java-based solution will be replaced by a different java-based solution. Usually only xml-based solutions are replaced by java-based solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a singleton you can use something along these lines:

```
@Service(value=MyService.myname)
public class MyService{
  public static final String myname = "myservicename";
}
```

Otherwise, I think you will have to use BeanNameAware.